# Saving Sender's Domain as Variable in Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, email, outlook, whois

Currently, I'm trying to create a sub that will read the selected email's "from" field, and set only the sender's domain as a variable:

So if I receive an email from someone@example.com, I can select the email, run the macro, and it will set example.com (not the entire email) as a variable I can use later.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Please remove `whois` tag as your question as nothing to do with this protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the board. Not sure why they downvoted you. But here is how to do what you asked.

```
Option Explicit

Public savedDomain As String

Public Sub Example()
    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim emailAddress As String
    If Not TypeName(Outlook.Application.ActiveWindow) = "Inspector" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set mi = Application.ActiveWindow.CurrentItem
    emailAddress = mi.SenderEmailAddress
    'Save it a variable like you asked.
    savedDomain = Mid(emailAddress, InStrRev(emailAddress, "@") + 1)
    'But... State loss can do weird things, so I'd save it to registry
    VBA.SaveSetting "MyExampleProgram", "SomeSectionName", "SavedDomain", savedDomain
    'You get it back like so:
    MsgBox VBA.GetSetting("MyExampleProgram", "SomeSectionName", "SavedDomain", vbNullString)
End Sub
```

Comment: The downvoter may not consider it good use of time to comment on one-day user posts, or at all on downvotes. Some receivers of downvotes do not see a comment as a learning opportunity so the downvoters choose to remain anonymous. As to the reason for downvoting see these for possible reasons. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270903/how-to-reduce-and-quickly-close-questions-that-are-merely-requirements.

Comment: Yes well, I admit I get annoyed with people who don't seem to put forth effort, but VBA is often someone's first language or first attempt to code. You get a lot of power users who are trying to spread their wings. So I usually cut people some slack within that tag. I also am not a big fan of crushing brand new users. Just my opinion. There are others:)